# convert folder rewrite rule from apache to nginx

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

These are my existing Apache htaccess rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule    ^$ myapp/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) myapp/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

After reading the other topics here I used this line in my nginx server block config to enable rewrites:

```
location / {
root /var/www/example.com/html;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

So basic rewrite works now but the problem is, files that sit in above mentioned apache folders now get called at root level (not from mentioned folders) which then results in 404 errors for these files.

How can I import my Apache rules properly into my nginx config?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:
The nginx root directive just needed to be changed to apache folder.